# T-SQL function to convert numeric to words?

Tags: sql-server, string, function, t-sql

I am struggling to build a function that can convert a number 0-9 in a string into the spelling word of it. Here is what I have so far, and I realize 'word' is not a built in conversion, it's just what my thoughts on how to construct this would be:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Numbers2Words]
    (@strText VARCHAR(1000))
RETURNS varchar(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WHILE PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @strText) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @strText = STUFF(@strText, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @strText), 1, CONVERT(word, PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @strText)))
    END
    RETURN @strText
END
```

The idea would be to input something like this:

```
  SELECT [dbo].[fn_Numbers2Word]('1900testnumber')
```

and return this:

```
  'oneninezerozerotestnumber'
```

I have tried functions that do entire numbers, but since my strings will have alphas they do not work. I also tried incorporating those functions into this function above with no luck. I'm sure it's just something I'm doing syntax wise.

Can anyone help me alter my above function so that it produces my desired result?

Comment: Sorry about that, it's Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: It's just digit-by-digit substitution you need, not e.g. 'one thousand nine hundred'? Then you could just do one search & replace per digit?

Comment: Wow, I feel smart now....  (Embarrassed)...  You are absolutely correct.  I was way over thinking this.

Comment: You way is very neat, if there was a way to just look up the word for a number in a string array by index, or a dictionary. But from a quick search I'm not sure SQL has them and a temporary table or join seems overkill.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you are just wanting a simple replacement then using nested replace would super crazy fast and simple. I would avoid using a scalar function here.

```
declare @strText varchar(1000) = '1900testnumber'

select replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(@strText, '1', ' one'), '2', 'two'), '3', 'three'), '4', 'four'), '5', 'five'), '6', 'six'), '7', 'seven'), '8', 'eight'), '9', 'nine'), '0', 'zero')
```

Comment: This is way smarter than looping digit by digit.

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun, here's another option that you could put into a function

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(max) = '1900testnumber'

Select @S = replace(@S,sFrom,sTo)
 From (values ('0','zero')
             ,('1','one')
             ,('2','two')
             ,('3','three')
             ,('4','four')
             ,('5','five')
             ,('6','six')
             ,('7','seven')
             ,('8','eight')
             ,('9','nine')
      ) A(sFrom,sTo)

Select @S
```

**Returns**

```
oneninezerozerotestnumber
```

Comment: String concatenation is undocumented feature. Are you confident it will apply correct order?

Comment: @JohnyL In this case, the order is not relevant, however, I do have some larger "token" apps where the order does matter, and you would simply need to add the order by.

Answer (score 0):

Brute force with [`CHOOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/logical-functions-choose-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> Returns the item at the specified index from a list of values in SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @num INT = 20;

SELECT CHOOSE(@num,
'one ',
'two ',
'three ',
'four ',
'five ',
'six ',
'seven ',
'eight ',
'nine ',
'ten',
'eleven ',
'twelve ',
'thirteen ',
'fourteen ',
'fifteen ',
'sixteen ',
'seventeen ',
'eighteen ',
'nineteen ',
'twenty',
'twenty-one ',
'twenty-two ',
'twenty-three ',
'twenty-four ',
'twenty-five ',
'twenty-six ',
'twenty-seven ',
'twenty-eight ',
'twenty-nine ',
'thirty',
'thirty-one ',
'thirty-two ',
'thirty-three',
'thirty-four ',
'thirty-five ',
'thirty-six ',
'thirty-seven ',
'thirty-eight ',
'thirty-nine ',
'forty',
'forty-one ',
'forty-two ',
'forty-three ',
'forty-four ',
'forty-five ',
'forty-six ',
'forty-seven ',
'forty-eight ',
'forty-nine ',
'fifty',
'fifty-one ',
'fifty-two ',
'fifty-three ',
'fifty-four ',
'fifty-five ',
'fifty-six ',
'fifty-seven ',
'fifty-eight ',
'fifty-nine ',
'sixty',
'sixty-one ',
'sixty-two ',
'sixty-three ',
'sixty-four ',
'sixty-five ',
'sixty-six ',
'sixty-seven ',
'sixty-eight ',
'sixty-nine ',
'seventy',
'seventy-one ',
'seventy-two ',
'seventy-three ',
'seventy-four ',
'seventy-five ',
'seventy-six ',
'seventy-seven ',
'seventy-eight ',
'seventy-nine ',
'eighty',
'eighty-one ',
'eighty-two ',
'eighty-three ',
'eighty-four ',
'eighty-five ',
'eighty-six ',
'eighty-seven ',
'eighty-eight ',
'eighty-nine ',
'ninety',
'ninety-one ',
'ninety-two ',
'ninety-three ',
'ninety-four ',
'ninety-five ',
'ninety-six ',
'ninety-seven ',
'ninety-eight ',
'ninety-nine'
)
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=046fa79624d18ebbe87b47851e4ec7e8)**

Comment: How do you propose using this to convert `'1900testnumber'` to `oneninezerozerotestnumber`?

Comment: @MartinSmith  I would first extract number. I know that my answer doesn't handle exactly OP case. Just wanted to show usage of CHOOSE for spelled words and check how many arguments can it take(more than 2k).